# wordpress rw meta box with multiple fields

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I seem to be having issues with RW Meta Box API as what I trying to create is have 2 fields on custom field.

as I wish to have field with text field for slider name as text and slider itself as integer using this for percentages

you can see the plugin api here on github https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box

below is sample of my code but as of right now I sure the id and name fields are conflicting so they are not saving as the array I need.

```
    /**
     * Get div HTML
     *
     * @param string $html
     * @param mixed  $meta
     * @param array  $field
     *
     * @return string
     */
    static function html( $html, $meta, $field )
    {
        if ( ! is_array( $meta ) ) $meta = ( array ) $meta;
        if ( ! is_array( $html ) ) $html = ( array ) $html;

        echo print_r($meta, true);
        //echo $field['id'];
        $html[] = sprintf(
            '<div class="clearfix">
                <input type="text" id="%s" name="%s" value="%s">
            </div>',
            $field['id'][0],
            $field['field_name'],
            $meta[0]
        );

        $html[] = sprintf(
            '<div class="clearfix">
                <div class="rwmb-slider" id="%s" data-options="%s"></div>
                <span class="rwmb-slider-value-label">%s<span>%s</span>%s</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="%s" value="%s" />
            </div>',
            $field['id'][1],
            esc_attr( json_encode( $field['js_options'] ) ),
            $field['prefix'], $meta[1], $field['suffix'],
            $field['field_name'], $meta[1]
        );
        return implode( '<br />', $html );
    }
```

anyone know how I can pull this off as I have tried everything and I had hired 4 people to try pull this off too and have failed to make this work for me.

Stephen

Comment: `if ( ! is_array( $meta ) ) $meta = ( array ) $meta;` That is an interesting approach that 4 people couldn't notice and suggest a better option ...

Comment: I know its driving me insane even the developer not been much help but I have already wrote too much using his api in my custom plugins so Kinda stuck with it now why I looking at way around it